# Predicting Uncertainty in Random Forest Regression

Tags: confidence-interval, random-forest, prediction-interval, uncertainty

Scenario: I'm trying to build a random forest regressor to accelerate probing a large phase space.  I'm using python/scikit-learn to perform the regression, and I'm able to obtain a model that has a reasonably low cross-validation error on known data split into training/test sets.

Now I'd like to begin asking my model how confident it is (I'm a bit confused about the difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals).  Currently I know how to return some estimator $y$ given data $x$, and now I'd like to be able to get a measure of uncertainty.  If the model is sufficiently uncertain, I'd like it to let me know so that I can add that case to the training set.

My impression is that random forests are an ensemble methods.  We grow $N$ decision trees, and then our predictor is given by:
$$
y = \sum_i^N w_iT_i\left(x\right)
$$
Where $w_i$ is some weight and $T_i(x)$ is the value predicted by the $i$-th tree.

Perhaps the simplest (and by no means most promising) approach would be to try to take something like a variance:

$$
\sigma^2 = \sum_i^N \left(T_i(x) - y(x)\right)^2
$$

[This guide](http://blog.datadive.net/prediction-intervals-for-random-forests/) seems to suggest we can do quantile analysis using each tree as an observation.  Unfortunately I'm not sure I follow that logic, because it seems to me that even for data points that were in the training set that there should be some variance among the trees.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56895/do-the-predictions-of-a-random-forest-model-have-a-prediction-interval/62908#62908) seems to mention the flaws in the above methods, however I unfortunately can't really follow what they suggest we do instead (as my skills in R aren't what they could be).  Can someone weigh in on whether this is the train I should be following, and perhaps help me understand what's going on?  I can't understand where to work in assumptions about the sample.  Seeing similar code in Python would likely be really helpful to me.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6473) also seems like it might be useful, but the terms/notations are entirely outside of my specialty, and its essentially unreadable to me right now.

While I've worked in statistics on an application level, it's been a while since my last formal class.  So part of the barrier to entry for me is terminology/symbol use.

Edited to provide more detail.

Comment: I've been wondering about this as well. I don't know what is standard practice. One thing I've thought about is doing a k-fold cross-validation and using the predicted values for each of the k-folds to create a distribution for the predicted values. From there, calculate the quantiles from that distribution. Kind of like doing a bootstrap. I think that approach would be slightly different from the the guide you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for an additional suggestion.  I'm currently trying to play around with the quantile approach I linked to see if that works as I'd hoped (I can't say I understand the theory terribly well, but it makes verifiable/falsifiable predictions).

Doing a k-fold cross validation the way you mentioned would (I think) be similar in principle to running different experiments designed to reach the same conclusion - a totally reasonable approach.  However, due to a quirk in my current setup (that may be an issue long-run) my training set is rather static.  I'll see if I can work around that.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the uncertainty of the RF predictions can be estimated using several approaches, one of them is the quantile regression forests method(Meinshausen, 2006), which estimates the prediction intervals. Other methods include U-statistics approach of Mentch & Hooker (2016) and monte carlo simulations approach of Coulston (2016).

Answer (score 1):

The problem of constructing prediction intervals for random forest predictions has been addressed in the following paper:

Zhang, Haozhe, Joshua Zimmerman, Dan Nettleton, and Daniel J. Nordman. "Random Forest Prediction Intervals." The American Statistician,2019.

The R package "rfinterval" is its implementation available at CRAN.

#### Installation

To install the R package *rfinterval*:

```
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github(repo="haozhestat/rfinterval")
install.packages("rfinterval")
library(rfinterval)
?rfinterval
```

#### Usage

Quickstart:

````
train_data <- sim_data(n = 1000, p = 10)
test_data <- sim_data(n = 1000, p = 10)

output <- rfinterval(y~., train_data = train_data, test_data = test_data,
                     method = c("oob", "split-conformal", "quantreg"),
                     symmetry = TRUE,alpha = 0.1)

### print the marginal coverage of OOB prediction interval
mean(output$oob_interval$lo < test_data$y & output$oob_interval$up > test_data$y)

### print the marginal coverage of Split-conformal prediction interval
mean(output$sc_interval$lo < test_data$y & output$sc_interval$up > test_data$y)

### print the marginal coverage of Quantile regression forest prediction interval
mean(output$quantreg_interval$lo < test_data$y & output$quantreg_interval$up > test_data$y)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to the site, @xiaolongmao.You may want to take our [tour]. Please do not post identical answers to multiple threads. Try to customize your answers to the specific question on each thread. If you have a case where you really believe that an identical answer completely answers the question, that implies the question is a duplicate. When you reach 50 reputation, you can post a comment to the OP. In the interim, you can flag the Q for closing as a duplicate.