# How to calculate the probability that a feature falls into a certain class

Tags: probability, distributions, unbalanced-classes

There are classes A,B,C,D,E. 
Variable x has different means for each of these classes, but there is overlap in the range of x among classes. 
Item counts are different between classes, eg. there are many more A's than B's etc. 
Given an item with a known value of x but unknown class, how do I calculate the probability of it falling into class A vs. class B vs. class C etc.

eg. If x is close to the mean value for class C, there may be 60% probablity of this item falling into class C, 20% for class B, 10% for class D,  7% for class A and 3% for class E.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the distribution of x in each class, other than just the mean? If you can represent x's distribution in each class by a normal distribution with known mean and variance, for example, the problem becomes much simpler.

Comment: @Nuclear Wang. Yes, x's distribution within each class is known. However, it is not a normal distribution. This phenomena tends to be very right skewed. Becomes more normal when log transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of probabilistic multiclass classification. A classical statistical approach is [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression). There are also many machine learning approaches, like [CARTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_and_regression_tree) or [Random Forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest).

(Multinomial) logistic regression automatically outputs conditional probabilities. For tree-based methods, you may need to specifically set a parameter. For instance, if you use the `randomForest` package in R, you need to apply `predict.randomForest(...,type=prob)`. Or use [a dedicated implementation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/358948/1352).