# Logistic regression vs. estimating $\beta$ using linear regression and applying the inverse-logit function

Tags: regression, logistic

If I want to perform a logistic regression analysis, can I use the linear regression model to compute the values of the parameters and then apply the formula:

$$\frac{1} {1 + \exp-(\beta_0+x_1\beta_1+\ldots +x_i\beta_i)}?$$

Comment: That would be a bad fit. Why would you ever do that?

Comment: why a bad fit ?

Comment: I think what @Memming means to say is that linear regression already supplies *some* kind of fit in the form of $\beta_0 + x_1\beta_1 + \cdots + x_i\beta_i.$ Applying the logistic function to these values is *really* going to screw up that fit, likely (but not invariably) making it worse. You can find out more by searching our site for (high-voted) answers about logistic regression and its interpretation: there are lots of them that should give you the insight you seek.

Comment: can you give me a link? please

Comment: A recent one is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69820 (I remember this because I provided an answer :-).  For others, you could begin with a [search on "logistic" and "regression"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic+regression?sort=votes&pageSize=15), but you'll have to wade through many of them because (unfortunately, IMHO) they often have a strong `R` orientation which makes them readable only by `R` aficianados.

Comment: I think there's a minus sign missing in the exponent, because the inverse logit function (a.k.a. the logistic function) is $1/(1+e^{-x})$.

Comment: Linear regression coefficients may serve as a good initializer for logistic regression, but as @whuber said is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea is a bit like Platt Scaling (see [this previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/why-use-platts-scaling) and the answers given), which is used to get probabilities from support vector machines and other machine learning methods.  You could use this method (although you would need to add a scaling and an offset to the output of the linear regression to make it work as well as possible), however for a linear model, there isn't really much benefit in doing so as it is straight-forward to construct a logistic regression model with similar computational expense, and that will probably give better estimates of probability.

Essentially for most problems it is best to use the statistical method that gives the most direct answer to the question posed, rather than use a simpler (or more complicated) method and post-process the result.

See also Appendix D.2 of Tipping's [paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/v1/tipping01a.html) on the Relevance Vector Machine, which explains why Platt scaling may not give as good a result as building a model that estimates the probability of class membership more directly.

Answer (score 5):

A linear regression relates proportions $p$ linearly to predictors $x_1, x_2, \dots$:
$$
    p = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \dots
$$
while a logistic regression relates log-odds linearly to $x_1, x_2, \dots$:
$$
   \log (p/(1-p)) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \dots
$$
Now, if you want to predict log-odds using linear regression (which is quite unnatural), you would clearly need to apply the logit function on predictions $\hat p$ from the linear regression, not the inverse logit as you propose. So my clear answer is "no, you should not use your formula".

Answer (score 0):

You need to estimate a logistic regression by maximum likelihood. The following link shows the likelihood function along with empirical maximization using Newton's method.

http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf

Comment: Just because ML is almost always used to estimate coefficients in a logistic regression does not mean it's the only way! We need to bear in mind that the *probability model* for our data and the *statistical procedure* we use to reason about our data with that model are different things. Logistic regression is, fundamentally, a *model*. Thus, Frank's question still stands unanswered: what is not right about the procedure he proposes?

Comment: @whuber  this page says that i have to minimize the sum of the squares http://archives.math.utk.edu/ICTCM/VOL13/C013/paper.html  but i see a lot of papers where it say to maximize the likelihood, them are both right ???  (here to says to minimize http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html)

Comment: (BTW, I don't think this answer deserves downvotes: it was offered in a helpful spirit and is not incorrect.)

Comment: Frank, they are indeed both correct for the most common form of regression where (among other things) the possible error of each observation has the same size no matter what value the observation may have.  That is almost never the case for binary observations. Minimizing the sum of squares it not a good way to carry out logistic regression. It can be done (as a crude initial estimate), but when it is *you don't change the answer!* You just use the prediction that is output by the least squares algorithm. Incidentally, as a general rule *no* statistical reference based on Excel is reliable.

Comment: +1 when you fit a model, the cost function you should optimise should reflect what is important about the problem you are trying to solve.  Starting with the likelihood is often a good step.

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I guess that I don't understand why you would want to estimate the logit model by OLS when ML yields efficient estimates and is available in virtually all software packages