# Machine learning tends to produce poorly-calibrated classifiers, but are the class ranks still valid?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ranking, calibration

In classification problems, "non-probabilistic" machine learning models such as boosted trees, neural networks, etc. are known to produce poorly-calibrated class scores, which aren't suitable for use as posterior probability estimates.

See e.g. ["On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks" (Guo et al, 2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04599) and ["Obtaining Calibrated Probabilities from Boosting" (Niculescu-Mizil & Caruana, 2012)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1403).

However, are the *rankings* of scores still generally valid?

For example, consider a classification neural network with 5 outputs. Is it valid to treat the output scores as ranks? Suppose the model predicts scores of A:0.64, B:0.23, C:0.10, D:0.02, and E:0.01. Is it valid to say that classes A-C are the "top 3" model predictions? Is it valid to say that class B is more probable than class C for this prediction?

I have done this many times in my own work, and I haven't seen it produce *bad* results. But I have also never considered if there are known problems with this procedure, either theoretical or empirical.

Comment: It probably depends on 100 different factors, but there's no logical reason why *poorly calibrated* (predicted probabilities aren't necessarily correct) has to mean the *rankings* (ordinal relations between the predicted probabilities) are poor.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. I suppose it's difficult to answer this question with a "yes", so I am mostly fishing to see if there is any strong "no" that I am not currently aware of.

Comment: Empirically, for a given model, wouldn't a probability calibration plot answer this question for you?

Comment: @RyanVolpi maybe! Would you just check for decreasing sections of the calibration plot?

Comment: That's what I would look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `sklearn` documentation discusses calibration.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-curve-py) One of the example models (in orange) is a naïve Bayes model that has a descending calibration curve, meaning that observations with larger estimated probabilities of occurrence actually occur less often.

[image: sklearn calibration]

A member of this community has posted an [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570095/how-to-calibrate-models-if-we-dont-have-enough-data) where the same phenomenon occurs but is even more visually extreme.

[image: The Great calibration]

Those seem to be examples where the rankings are wrong.